# Apply softbody result to CURVE

Tags: bezier-curves, shape-keys, soft-body

When one wants to 'save' the result of a softbody simulation, they apply the softbody modifier either directly to the mesh or as a shapekey. I am trying to perform this on a curve (simulating a string) but applying the modifier results in a message saying

> Cannot apply modifier for this object type

Curves support shapekeys, so it seems to be an arbitrary limitation of Blender. Is there some work around I can use to 'save' the result of the simulation as the curve's default shape?

Comment: convert the result to a mesh, then back to a curve. You will lose some bezier data, but you'll have a curve back